# Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to execute a spring logic which will create a jdbc table.
However on executing the code I am getting the following error.

```
Jun 18, 2017 4:15:19 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [springConfig.xml]
Jun 18, 2017 4:15:19 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:443)
    at springExample.JDBCCreateTableTemplate.createTable(JDBCCreateTableTemplate.java:18)
    at springExample.ClientLogic.main(ClientLogic.java:19)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:715)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:564)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:162)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:411)
    ... 21 more
```

This is my springConfig.xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>

    <bean id="id1"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" />
        <property name="username" value="admin" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="id2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="id1" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="id3" class="springExample.JDBCCreateTableTemplate">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate">
            <ref bean="id2" />
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is my JDBCCreateTemplate file

```
    package springExample;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class JDBCCreateTableTemplate {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    void createTable(){
        jdbcTemplate.execute("create table springtest(sno number(3), sname varchar(10))");
        System.out.println("Table created");
    }
}
```

And this is my ClientLogic file

```
package springExample;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class ClientLogic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Resource res = new ClassPathResource("springConfig.xml");
        BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);

        JDBCCreateTableTemplate jdbcCreateTableTemplate = (JDBCCreateTableTemplate) beanFactory.getBean("id3");
        jdbcCreateTableTemplate.createTable();

    }

}
```

Comment: is your database up and running?

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.